# TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex when dtype is datetime64[ns]

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, sampling

I have a pandas dataframe in Python with a column such as this:

```
 df.Timestamp
```

> ```
> ...   ..................
> 129   2018-09-12 21:40:00
> 130   2018-09-12 21:50:00
> 131   2018-09-12 22:00:00
> 132   2018-09-12 22:10:00
> 133   2018-09-12 22:20:00
> 134   2018-09-12 22:30:00
> 135   2018-09-12 22:40:00
> 136   2018-09-12 22:50:00
> 137   2018-09-12 23:00:00
> 138   2018-09-12 23:10:00
> 139   2018-09-12 23:20:00
> 140   2018-09-12 23:30:00
> 141   2018-09-12 23:40:00
> 142   2018-09-12 23:50:00
> Name: Timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]
> ```

Type of individual element is:

```
type(df.Timestamp[0])
```

> ```
> datetime.datetime
> ```

When I try resampling, following error occurs:

```
df.Timestamp.resample('2H')
```

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex

I have tried `pd_todatetime` but it does not work. 
As far as I know, my datatype is right as it is datetime.datetime
None of the solutions I viewed had an answer for this type of problem.

What can be the solution?

Comment: which means you need to set your `Timestamp` column as index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 possible solutions - parameter `on` in [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) or create `DatetimeIndex` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

Last add some aggregate function like `sum`, `mean`...:

```
df.resample('2H', on='Timestamp').sum()
```

---

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('2H').sum()
```

Comment: @Sandeep Kadapa - Thank you.